# Magento - using $this->getPriceHtml on custom page template

Tags: magento, php

I have a scroller showing a collection of products currently on sale, which I call using the following:

```
$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
    ->setPageSize(4) // Only return 4 products
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
           0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
           1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
           ), 'left')
    ->addAttributeToSort('special_from_date', 'desc');
$_productCollection->load();
```

I then run a foreach to get the individual products:

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)
```

Everything works fine, except for the price, which I would usually call using

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)
```

However this is giving me a blank. If I do a var_dump I can see that both the original price and the special price are both available, so why isn't this working? I use exactly the same code on my homepage template, which I call through the homepage CMS, and the price is shown fine (with the regular price crossed out and special price shown).

Using **$_product->getFinalPrice()** works fine, but only gives me the final "special" price and doesn't show the original price.

Am I maybe missing something in my xml layout that's needed to show the prices using **getPriceHtml**?

Comment: What block does `$this` refer to?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue is that `getPriceHtml()` function is defined in the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product` block, rather than the standard `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.  You need to ensure that your block extends the Product block, or you can achieve that in your layout by something like:

```
<block type="catalog/product" name="blockname" template="path/to/template.phtml">
```

I haven't tested that, but it should work.

Comment: Bingo. I was using core/template, so changed to catalog/product_list and now it's working. New it was gonna be something simple like that. Cheers!

Answer (score 32):

My colleague recommended using this Magento friendly method to get the price html anywhere:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
      $productBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price');
      echo $productBlock->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
```

If you're already working with a loaded product then you won't need the first line, however my product was from a collection so this was necessary.

Comment: this worked even better than the accepted answer for me.

Comment: This is the correct way to go, the accepted answer but isn't recommended because it uses a path.

Answer (score 6):

You could also try this:

```
<?php echo Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Where `$_product` relates to the product object.

Comment: Are you referring to a product-object with $_product?

Comment: Yes. Magento doesn't like me accessing Mage_Catalog_Block_Product directly (I forget the exact error, but that's what it meant)

Comment: Using $this when not in object context in D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product.php on line 63

Comment: works perfect and you dont need to change block type! tanx
edit: using magento 1.7

Comment: Lol, neither `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product` nor `getPriceHtml` are static - cant work anyways

Answer (score 3):

To get getPriceHtml() function work correctly in your custom block you need 2 things

1)Make your block type catalog/product

```
<block type="catalog/product" name="home_page_product" after="default_home_page" template="custom/home_page_product.phtml"/>
```

2)Pass the product object to getPriceHtml() function

```
<?php $productObject = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($productObject, true) ?>
```