# Using getChildHtml inside included template magento

Tags: php, templates, magento

I am trying to use `$this->getChildHtml('head')` from inside a `page/html/header.phtml` file in Magento.

Using `$this->getChildHtml('head')` inside thh `page/1column.phtml` file works as expected.

Can someone point me in the right direction to understand how the magic `$this` is used within templates?

I think this [Stack overflow question, Magento - using $this->getPriceHtml on custom page template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652808/magento-using-this-getpricehtml-on-custom-page-template) is on the right lines, but I'm still missing something. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are getting in to "world inside a world that is bigger than the world that you are inside" syndrome here. You can't use it because head is not defined a child of your block that you are currently in.

try this instead:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: +1 thanks, your solution didn't work first time because I forgot to `echo` it!

Comment: I love your syndrome's name :)

Comment: How to do fix that `not defined a child of your block` part??

Comment: @mrN you reference it to your layout nodes. simple

Comment: @AntonS, I have pretty basic, can you point me to a resource.. that elaborates what you are saying.

Comment: @mrN start with magento knowledge base and theme/layout related articles